# Un-indenting lines in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an equivalent to `editor.actions.indentLines` that moves the selected lines to the left instead of to the right?

I know you can use Tab / Shift+Tab for indenting. But unfortunately, that does not work in Vim mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called "outdenting".  See the command:

```
{
  "key": "shift+tab",
  "command": "outdent",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus"
}
```

Just set it to a different keybinding.  You can search for "shift tab" in the keybindings to try to figure out what command it is already bound to - in this case "outdent".

EDIT:  Actually I see that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> is already bound to outdent so you could try that as well.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Comment: I will just add that the commands `editor.action.indentLines` and `editor.action.outdentLines` are eachothers oposite. Using `tab` to indent a line requires the cursor to be at the beginning of the line whereas neither of these commands requires it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You have `editor.action.reindentLines` but instead of working as `Shift + Tab`, it *resets* the indentation.

There is an open issue ([Help Sublime Text users migrate to VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32890)) which seems to be mapping this. You could upvote there and maybe comment, asking for the VS Code team to add this command as well.