# Indenting multilines/block with vscode and vim plugin

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, formatting

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572646/un-indenting-lines-in-vs-code) is already on the site, but it doesn't work for me.  I'm not 100% sure the answer is responsive to my situation (the question asks about vim "mode").  If it is, the context for the accepted answer isn't obvious for me.

I assume were supposed to splice the JSON fragment

```json
{
  "key": "shift+tab",
  "command": "outdent",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus"
}
```

into our settings but it's not clear how or where.  The app has a settings.json, a keybindings.json and the plugin has package.json.

I got this to work in vim itself a year or so ago IIRC, but it took a plugin and a couple of settings.

Edit to add: ctrl+[ and ctrl+] aren't functional for me.  Presumably they would be w/o the vim plugin, but the plugin overrides the ctrl commands.

Answer (score 6):

Just as in normal vim, typing `>>` and `<<` in normal mode or `>` and `<` in visual mode will indent and un-indent lines, respectively.

Source:  https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Shifting_blocks_visually

Also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/235841/7007605

Comment: Yes. Only the first time, then use `.` to repeat the indentation.

Comment: The lose selection after first `>` issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69664536/indent-multiple-times-with-vscode-and-vim-extension?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the main Vim (VSCodeVim), the standard `m>`, `m<`, `:m,n>`, `:m,n<` are not supported (see https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/3733).

However, this feature is supported by the `Neo Vim` VS Extension (`asvetliakov.vscode-neovim`).  Note that if you go this route, you do need to install neovim (`>v0.5.0`)  separately, which you can obtain at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/nightly.  Then set the path to the neovim executable/binary in the `Neo Vim` VS extension settings.

Answer (score 0):

I remaped `<` and `>` in normal mode to ident lines while using the VSCode commands:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<"],
        "commands" : ["tab"]
    },
    {
        "before": [">"],
        "commands" : ["outdent"]
    }
 ]
```